# Static site in sub folder under Drupal will not load

Tags: php, drupal, dreamweaver

I have a created a static site containing only a few pages which will reside in a sub-folder under a drupal install, for some reason only pages which are part of a dreamweaver template cause drupal to serve an error message. Is there some config setting within drupal the can be set to ignore the sub-folder, below is a link to the index.html page of the sub-folder

http://www.diaceutics.com/dxlaunchplanner/

Comment: The directory is returning 500 error, which I think Drupal is handling, I would check the config of my web server if the files are allowed to be served, do you have an `index` file in that directory ?

Comment: Yes, index.html, it only happens with pages which are part of a dreamweaver template

Answer (score 3):

Add this on the top of your root *htaccess* in order to ignore the drupal rewrite rules for the `dxlaunchplanner` folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^dxlaunchplanner/ - [L]
</IfModule>
```

The `-` means that it should pass through the URI and do nothing, and the flag `[L]` means that it should skip all the following rewrite rules. So the combination of both will make Apache ignore the other rewrite rules.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried the below but it is making no difference??

Comment: RewriteRule ^dxlaunchplanner/ - [L]

Comment: Try the updated code - if you placed the rule before `RewriteEngine On` it will not working. You need to place it at the top of the htaccess.

Comment: Still doesn't work, I don't think this is a rewrite issue, I've created an another .html page "index2.html" which unlike "index.html" does not use a .dwt Template, but it works

Comment: All right so the rule is working. The problem seems to be that the index.html generate a 500 error that Drupal handle. You should check on your server log to see what is breaking here.